# MQTT data compression

Tags: compression, mqtt

At the moment I am trying to find out if MQTT supports automatic compression of data. For example, if I combine MQTT with TLS, I can use the compression options of TLS. Is there anything similar for MQTT? Or does the publishing application have to compress its data itself and can then send the compressed data with MQTT?

So far, I've read around and couldn't find any specific information about whether MQTT supports data compression or not.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

MQTT is purely a transport, it will carry what ever bytes you give it as a payload (up to 256MB) and not change them in any way.

If you want to compress the payload first then that is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a wrapper class called JZIP for my UFM (Universal File Mover) open source Java project.  You can download the source code from [here](https://capitalware.com/ufm_tryit.html).

Here is the just the JZip class.  It has 2 methods: compressData & decompressData.  Both expect a byte[] for input and gives a byte[] as output.  It is super simple to use.

```
package com.capitalware.ufm.handlers;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import com.capitalware.ufm.UFM;

/**
 * This class will handle all of UFM's compression and decompression work.
 * @author Roger Lacroix
 * @version 1.0
 * @license Apache 2 License
 */
public class JZip
{
   /**
    * The constructor - make sure nothing instantiates this class.
    * It must be accessed in a static way.
    */
   private JZip()
   {}

   /**
    * This method will compress a byte array of data.
    *
    * @param inputData an array of bytes
    * @return byte array of the contents of the file.
    */
   public static byte[] compressData(byte[] inputData)
   {
      // Create the compressor with highest level of compression
      Deflater compressor = new Deflater();
      compressor.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);

      // Give the compressor the data to compress
      compressor.setInput(inputData);
      compressor.finish();

      // Create an expandable byte array to hold the compressed data.
      // You cannot use an array that's the same size as the orginal because
      // there is no guarantee that the compressed data will be smaller than
      // the uncompressed data.
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(inputData.length);

      // Compress the data
      byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
      while (!compressor.finished())
      {
         int count = compressor.deflate(buf);
         bos.write(buf, 0, count);
      }
      try
      {
         bos.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         UFM.logger.fatal("IOException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }

      // return compressed data
      return bos.toByteArray();
   }

   /**
    * This method will decompress a byte array of compressed data.
    *
    * @param compressedData an array of bytes
    * @return byte array of uncompressed data
    */
   public static byte[] decompressData(byte[] compressedData)
   {
      // Create the decompressor and give it the data to compress
      Inflater decompressor = new Inflater();
      decompressor.setInput(compressedData);

      // Create an expandable byte array to hold the decompressed data
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(compressedData.length);

      // Decompress the data
      byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
      while (!decompressor.finished())
      {
         try
         {
            int count = decompressor.inflate(buf);
            bos.write(buf, 0, count);
         }
         catch (DataFormatException e)
         {
            UFM.logger.fatal("DataFormatException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
      }
      try
      {
         bos.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         UFM.logger.fatal("IOException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }

      // return uncompressed data
      return bos.toByteArray();
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked, which was does MQTT support compression, not how do I compress data with Java...

Comment: You gave the person the correct answer and I was providing a solution based on your answer.